# How to transfer file using IOUtils.copy through Java Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, distributed-computing

I am currently working with Java Sockets. I have created a server side code and client side code to transfer file through socket. I have successfully transferred the files from client to server with in the same system, but if I tried with the different systems in different platform, then it is not working. The server side and client side codes are given below.

Server side code

```
public class FileTransferTestServer extends Thread{

    private final Socket socket;

    public FileTransferTestServer(Socket socket) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection Established with "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
            new FileTransferTestServer(socket).start();
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String buffer = null;
            String fileName = null;

            if((buffer = br.readLine()) != null){
                fileName = buffer;
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            int res = IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
            System.out.println("res : "+res);
            is.close();
            fos.flush();fos.close();
            br.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Client Side Code

```
public class FileTransferClient {

    public FileTransferClient() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("172.16.4.23",5000);
            File file = new File("/Users/Guest/Desktop/DQM.txt");
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
            out.println("file-transfer");
            out.flush();
            out.println(""+file.getName());
            out.flush();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            int res = IOUtils.copy(fis, outputStream);
            out.flush();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            fis.close();
            System.out.println("res : "+res);
            socket.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

How to make this program to transfer files between system

I have tried with Windows (Server) & Mac OS X(Client) and Windows (Server) & LinuxMint(Client)

Note : 
1. I want to send File Name followed by file content.
2. File content may be in any form (Text or Binary file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix test and binary in the same stream unless you really know what you are doing.  In this case the BufferedReader assumes you will only use this reader from now on and it can read as much data as is available.  This means it can read data you intended to be for the file.

I suggest you use DataInput/OutputStream, and only this.  You can use writeUtf/readUTF for the  text.

To write

```
Socket socket = new Socket("172.16.4.23",5000);
String pathname = "/Users/Guest/Desktop/DQM.txt";
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
outputStream.writeUTF(pathname);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pathname);
int res = IOUtils.copy(fis, dos);
fis.close();
dos.close();
socket.close();
```

To read

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
String fileName = dis.readUTF();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
int res = IOUtils.copy(dis, fos);
fos.close();
socket.close();
```

Comment: Yeah, Its working :). Thanks [Peter Lawrey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey)